# { code: -32000, message: 'invalid sender' } - Truffle deployment with Infura endpoint to Rinkeby

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, infura

I am having trouble with deployment of a project contract to the Rinkeby network using @truffle/hdwallet-provider and an Infura endpoint. Here is the code for deploy.js:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const compiledFactory = require('./build/CampaignFactory.json');
 
const provider = new HDWalletProvider('INSERT MNEMONIC', 'INSERT INFURA ENDPOINT');
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
 
const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
 
  console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);
 
  const interface = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(compiledFactory.abi));
  const bytecode = '0x'+compiledFactory.evm.bytecode.object;
 
  const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
    .deploy({ data: bytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0] })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
 
  console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

Here are the versions of modules I used:

```
+-- @truffle/hdwallet-provider@1.3.0
+-- solc@0.8.4
`-- web3@1.3.5
Node.js v14.15.5.
```

This is the error I am catching:

```
Attempting to deploy from account 0x45A33AAC570CdCda443c85B08DdFb94751951Cbe
{ code: -32000, message: 'invalid sender' }
(node:28960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at deploy (D:\My stuff\programming\ethereum\kickstart\ethereum\deploy.js:22:46)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:28960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:28960) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Has anyone encountered this issue and knows how to solve? I don't understand the invalid sender error as it seems like the correct account is retrieved. I am able to deploy on a local ganache network. Will appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi! Does the address in `accounts[0]` have any Rinkeby ETH?

Comment: also, could you detail how you're connecting to Rinkeby (the `truffle-config` with the provider details (take out any api keys first)?

Comment: @LinumLabs Hey, thanks for the response. I'm new to this so bare with me (:
Yes, accounts[0] has Rinkeby ETH (18 ETH). It seems to be recognized as I see that it is attempting to deploy from that account in the console log.
To connect to Rinkeby I am using the truffle-hdwallet-provider and the Infura API. I don't see a truffle-config.js file. I assume it is because I only installed the hdwallet-provider? In the code, I set the provider with the command `new HDWalletProvider('mnemonic', 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/API')`.